# Is it more performant to check if element exists before running functions in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Two **example** functions on a script loaded on to a site:

```
function doSomething() {
    var a, b, c;
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('#container p');

    if (el.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = a+b;

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        console.log(el)
        el[i].style.marginTop = a+b+i+'px';
    }
}

doSomething();


function doSomethingElse() {
    var a, b, c;
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('#container p');

    a = 10;
    b = 20;
    c = a+b;

    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].style.marginTop = a+b+i+'px';
    }
}

if (document.querySelectorAll('#container p').length) {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Two questions:

1. Would either of those occupy browser resources if `#container` did NOT exist? e.g; Would the variables be assigned, stored in memory, would any calculations get done, etc.
2. Is there any difference between the two approaches if the above is true? As one checks when function is run, one before.

I don't think this has already been asked, least I couldn't find it. I imagined it would of been a common query. I'm asking more about the principle rather than the exact code I've given as an example here, more so to much larger/complicated functions.

Thanks.

Comment: You're worried about mirco-optimizations, yet are using jQuery? Even without the overhead of jQuery, any difference would be insignificant.

Comment: Well it was more out of prinicple and jquery was just an example to be honest. Would it help if I amended it to vanilla? Though I'm not negating your point :)

Comment: Updated and remove the jQuery.

Comment: The principle will depend on the exact code you're comparing. So then with jQuery removed, it's a question of whether the extra DOM selection (assuming elements are found) is worth it. As with all of these sorts of questions, you should test to find out. The results may differ between different browsers and versions. That said, if you're trying to do as little work as possible, I'd take the second one, do the DOM selection, store the result to a variable, check its length, and pass it to the function if elements were found. That way you have exactly 1 DOM selection, and potentially no...

Comment: ...function call. However, like I said in the first comment, any difference here is going to be insignificant unless this code is running thousands of times per second. The elimination of that function call just isn't going to make a difference. I'd choose whichever is cleaner and more maintainable, and look for better ways to optimize, like ditching jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with your doSomething() function, since with doSomethingElse() you are selecting `#container p` twice, so the browser will have to find it twice, which may impact performance.

As for checking if it exists, that will have very little impact, since your for loop won't do anything with an empty array anyway (since 0 is not less than 0).